# Django: url dispatcher

Tags: python, django

I am trying to configure my Django url dispatcher. I want `/results` to render my `results` template, and `/results/3` to render my `user_results` template, with an argument of `3`, for example. If I use the following code:

```
url(r'^results/', views.results, name='results'),
url(r'^results/(\d+)/$', views.user_results, name='user_results')
```

then both `/results` and `/results/3` just load render the `results` template. However, if I comment out the first line, then `/results/3` renders the `user_results` template, as expected.

Why is `/results/3` only matching the second url when the first one is omitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/results/3` is matching your url pattern because your regular expression does not have the end-of-string `$`. Note the difference between the following:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'^results/', 'results/3')  # no end of string $
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02BFD3D8>
>>> re.match(r'^results/$', 'results/3')
```

The easiest (and probably best) thing to do is to add an end-of-string `$` to your first url pattern:

```
url(r'^results/$', views.results, name='results'),
url(r'^results/(\d+)/$', views.user_results, name='user_results')
```

Otherwise, you can reverse your url patterns. As soon as a matching url pattern is found, the dispatcher will stop searching through the url patterns and will dispatch immediately. Try this instead:

```
url(r'^results/(\d+)/$', views.user_results, name='user_results'),  # will dispatch here and stop searching url patterns if a digit occurs after results
url(r'^results/', views.results, name='results')
```

Comment: Thanks, that works well! However, I'm still not sure why `/results/3` is matching to `r'^results/'` ...?

Comment: @Karnivaurus I edited my answer above to answer your question.